# Failed to launch application server, server thread existing on windows

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I used the EnterpriseDB postgresql installer from their website, but when I finished and ran pgadmin (that came installed with postgresql) I get a configuration error that says:

```
An error occurred initializing the application server:

Failed to launch application server, server thread existing
```

It then asks me to input a python path and an application path. For the python path I assume it's `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\` which is where I have python installed. However i am not sure which application it's asking about.

9.6.3 version of postgresql. the pgadmin version is 4. windows 10 64bit

Comment: Here's an answer to the same error message on ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/q/1089483/800003

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same issue and found 'PYTHONPATH' system variable is causing the problem. So i deleted the environment variable and it worked fine. Fortunately i was not using these variables since my development environment is in remote.

So try removing 'PYTHONHOME' or 'PYTHONPATH' from the environment variable list and launch the application.

From the pgAdmin code,

```
# For unknown reason the Qt runtime does not pass the environment
# variables (i.e. PYTHONHOME, and PYTHONPATH), to the Python
# sub-processes, leading to failures executing background processes.
#
# This has been observed only on windows. On *nix systems, it is likely
# picking the system python environment, which is good enough to run
# the process-executor.**
```

Comment: I m facing this issue on ubuntu. Any Tip ?

Comment: I was facing with this issue too on my windows 10. I forced to use psql dump because I haven't any solutions for pgAdmin now i'm doing the dump by this commands:

/psql.exe -U postgres 
\l - a list of the databases 
\c - connect to current db 
\i - import sql dump with the OS path (e.g. C:\DUMP\dump.sql for windows)

maybe will be useful as temporary solution

Comment: I do not have these environment variables and pgAdmin 4 does not work any more at home.

Comment: On windows I fixed this by deleting all files in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin